# Gazebo shows more robots than robot launched number

Tags: ros, robotics, gazebo-simu

Every-time I launch Gazebo, there is a default turtlebot that always appears in the simulation although I don't launch him.

There is a black robot (called mobile_base), it appeared although I didn't launch it).

To simplify the problem, even when I am loading just gazebo empty world without my robots, this default robot (mobile_base) appears in the simulation.
Do you have an idea how can I remove this default robot from Gazebo simulation? Thank you!

EDIT: solved by launching different world, that doesn't contain a default turtlebot.

Comment: Send how you launch the program and the launch file.

Comment: How about in the terminal what command do you use to launch gazebo?

Comment: @eggrobot78 I edited the post, please notice that this problem appears in any launches that I made, therefore I think it's gazebo defaults issue. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to delete `mobile-base` or start new gazebo world?

Comment: @eggrobot78 The problem was that I launched a world with a default turtlebot. Thank you very much! If you can help with my another issue please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55875980/robotics-move-multiple-turtlebots-separately   Thank you!!